# Create a ADB loopback in Android

Tags: android, adb, loopback

I have to create an application that can perform adb operations on the user's device without an adb server running on a desktop machine.
I stumbled upon ADB loopback, it consisted of adding a VPN/WIFI certificate on the device, then pairing the device locally and after that, the application is able to run adb commands from the application.

There was this github repo:
https://web.archive.org/web/20201030143635/https://github.com/gersseba/android-touchlogger

Also, there is an application named Automate, which does the same thing.
Does anyone know how can I do the same in Android java?

Comment: The repo you mention is available without any problems: https://github.com/gersseba/android-touchlogger

Comment: Yeah, actually I was getting a 500 before, but even after I took its clone, it's not working since process builder doesn't have those privileges it used to have, to run the adb process